# VB.NET: Scrollbar's value

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar

So, in my vertical scrollbar, the maximum value is 16.

In my application, I made a Label to track the scrollbar's value, just for testing purposes.

I noticed that when I move the bar to the bottom, the value is 6. And when a [i]release[/i] the button (stop holding it with the mouse), the value becomes 7.

Something similar goes when I move the button to the top: It is 1, and when I release the button, it becomes 0.

That's a bit weird, but what mainly bugs me is why I cannot reach value 16?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seem to be a bug or an expected behavior with LargeChange property

set it to 1 and you get what you want